# How to create ROC curve from multiple classification models

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, data-analysis, roc, knime

How to create ROC curve from several classification models in order to compare them with each other. I'm using KNIME analytics platform.

Comment: ... are you asking what a ROC curve is?

Comment: of course no, but i'm asking if there is a possiblity to create a ROC curve from different models in order to compare them to each other through KNIME platform.

Answer (score 1):

In order to compare the classification model on the basis of ROC curve, the best way is to create the three separate ROC curve for each classification model.

After that compare the area under the ROC curve of each model because accuracy is measured by the area under the ROC curve. The one with a higher value of the area under ROC is the best classification model.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite easy. You just need to compute the probabilities/normalized class distribution values and put them in the same table. In the ROC view nodes you can specify them for the positive class and see the ROC curves:

[image: View of ROC nodes, configuration of the JS ROC node]